# How are relative pronouns pronouns?

Tags: terminology

Pronouns usually replace nouns or noun phrases. There are a few fuzzy examples where it's not as clear cut as that (e.g. "my" which refers to me but acts like a determiner, and "mine" which refers to both me and something else).

How are relative pronouns like [*that*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that#Pronoun) and [*which*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/which#Pronoun) pronouns? What noun or noun phrase do they replace? If they're not strictly speaking pronouns, what would be a better description for them?

Examples from Wiktionary:

> - The CPR course **that** she took really came in handy.
> - The house **that** he lived in was old and dilapidated.
> - We've met some problems **which** are very difficult to handle.

I'm not talking about other clearly pronominal uses such as:

> - **Which** is **which**?
> - **That** is **that**!

Comment: Preliminary point: "my" and "mine" are both genitive pronouns functioning in NP structure; the former as Determiner, the latter as Head. Relative pronouns like "which", "who", "whom" typically have a nominal as antecedent, from which they derive their interpretation, so in that respect they can broadly be seen as replacing a noun. Note that "that" is not strictly speaking a pronoun but a subordinator.

Comment: @BillJ It's not the antecedent which determines whether it's a pronoun or not, it's the gap that it correlates with in the relative clause itself.

Comment: @Araucaria That won't work because not all relative clauses have gaps. The relativized element (or gap if there is one) derives its interpretation from the antecedent which is almost always a nominal.

Comment: @BillJ The OED terms 'our' as A a pronoun (the genitive of 'us') and B an adjective - which indicates possession.

Comment: @NigelJ "our" is semantically a pronoun and grammatically a determiner.

Comment: "*The CPR course*, *the CPR course* she took, really came in handy."  You can replace the relative pronoun with its antecedent.  The punctuation is different, but that's just writing mechanics.  This sentence means the exact same thing as "The CPR course that she took really came in handy."

Comment: @NigelJ OED is the best when it comes to semantics. Very good when it comes to pragmatics (though modern usages are often picked up more quickly by other good dictionaries). But, like most other dictionaries, leagues away from the best grammars when it comes to grammar (and POS determination is in the domain of grammar).

Answer (score 4):

It's a fairly common viewpoint that the "that" used to introduce relative clauses is not in fact a pronoun.

*Which* is like a pronoun in the following way.
Just as *they* in the pair of sentences "We've met some problems. **They** are very difficult to handle" can be seen as replacing a noun phrase like  "those problems", the word *which* in "We've met some problems which are very difficult to handle" can be seen as standing for a noun phrase like "those problems". Of course, you couldn't use the actual noun phrase "those problems" in the same position, but the pronoun *which* is understood to mean something along those lines.

Comment: It's *not* the antecedent which determines whether it's a pronoun or not, it's the syntactic function of the gap that it correlates within the relative clause itself.

Comment: Take for example, *the place where we met* versus *the place which sells food*.

Comment: Or, *Sally ate my chocolates, which annoyed me*

Comment: H&P call *that* a subordinator, not a relativiser, btw.

Answer (score 0):

*In the main sentence*, the whole subordinate clause acts as an adjective phrase. These kind of subordinate clauses are usually called “relative clauses”, but sometimes also “adjective clauses” for this reason.

- “that she took” replaces “taken” in *The **taken** CPR course really came in handy.*
- “that he lived in” replaces “inhabited” in *The **inhabited** house was old and dilapidated.*
- “which are very difficult” replaces “hard” in *We've met some **hard** problems.*

*Inside the relative clause*, the relative pronoun replaces its antecedent, which is typically a noun phrase or a noun.

- “that” replaces “the CPR course” in *She took **the CPR course**.*
- “that” replaces “the house” in *He lived in **the house**.*
- “which” replaces “Some problems” in ***Some problems*** are difficult to handle.